# How to create custom tagging policy (Require 'ProjectName' tag) for all Azure resources

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I’m working on to create policies in Azure. I want to create “Require ‘ProjectName’ tag for all resources” policy for all Azure resources. For this I have followed this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies), but I’m unable to configure this policy.

So, can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed [Assign policies for tag compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies) documentation to resolve the above issue. I have used `Require a tag on resources` built-in policy.

During the assignment of this policy to the subscription level, I have mentioned `tagname(ProjectName)` under the `parameters` section.